# Execute after base64 decode

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the below command

```sh
echo 'IHBpbmcgZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQo=' | base64 -d
```

which will give ping google.com

I want to execute the ping google.com after base64 decoding

```sh
echo 'IHBpbmcgZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQo=' | base64 -d | ?
```

What should be the command for ? after piping the base64 -d
I did xargs but didnt execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`echo 'IHBpbmcgZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQo=' | base64 -d`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$echo 'IHBpbmcgZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQo=' | base64 -d  |  bash 
PING google.com(maa05s02-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4007:80c::200e)) 56 data bytes
```